# how to parse web page over firewall

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse a web url with this [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.*url*.com").get();
String title = doc.title();
System.out.println("title: "+title);
```

I always get the error below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 403 error loading URL http://www.*url*.com
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:327)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:130)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:119)
    at HttpRequestPoster.main(HttpRequestPoster.java:151)
```

My computer is a member of network which is controlled by kerio winroute firewall. Before internet connetions we connect to firewall from our web browsers. The reason must be this. How can i parse the url ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the user agent worked for me.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2").get();
```

Comment: There's an [`userAgent()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html#userAgent%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP error 403](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4) just means `Forbidden`.

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.

In other words, the server side decided based on the request-specific information that the requester isn't allowed to receive the response. That can have many causes: specific information is missing in request headers, the IP address is disallowed, the user agent is disallowed, etcetera.

Your most honest bet would be contacting the admin of the website in question, asking for clarification and permission. You could also use a real webbrowser and track using a HTTP traffic tracker like Firebug or Fiddler2 to check the request/response details. Jsoup's [`HttpConnection` class](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/HttpConnection.html) at least offers several methods to set headers, cookies and/or user agent whenever necessary.